# expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, object

I am working on this JavaScript and cannot get it to display to HTML. I see it in the console but all I see on the page is my name.

Create an object called "me" that describes you with your name, city, and job title.

```
//    Display the content of the object in the HTML page.
var me = {
  name: "Roxann",
  city: "Denver",
  jobTitle: "Paralegal"
};

console.log(me);

document.getElementById("q1").innerHTML = me.name, me.city, me.jobTitle;
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect an expression like `left = right1, right2, right3, ...` to evaluate to?

Comment: You're not concatenating the bits of the string correctly, see MDN [*Arithmetic operators*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition).

Comment: Thanks @RobG. Our professors told us MDN might be too hard to understand but that was a great resource.

Comment: @poprox—MDN is great, but it's a public wiki so not normative. Use ECMA-262 for that. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
document.getElementById("q1").innerHTML = "Name:"+me.name+ ", City:"+me.city+", "+ me.jobTitle;
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't helpful. You should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.

Comment: Ohh Ok @RobG, I will take care of it.

Comment: @Shubhranshu I appreciate the help But I am in a position to have to learn and understand WHY I need to enter it in that manner. but, good looking out!

Comment: @poprox Noone knows everything. I am also here to learn . So I can understand tha t I should explain the WHY.

Answer (score 1):

Since innerHTML holds strings (html string) you have to build the html contents first:

```
var html = me.name + ', ' + me.city + ', ' + me.jobTitle;
document.getElementById("q1").innerHTML = html;
```

or using ES6:

```
document.getElementById("q1").innerHTML = `${me.name}, ${me.city}, ${me.jobTitle}`;
```

Comment: Thanks. I will have to remember innerHTML holds strings. I have 10 more of these to go.

Answer (score 0):

The variable declaration `me` was fine. All the data is there. To set it in the `.innerHTML` correctly, try something like this instead:

```
document.getElementById("q1").innerHTML = [me.name, me.city, me.jobTitle].join(' ');
```

Or, for each on it's own line, you can do:

```
document.getElementById("q1").innerHTML = [me.name, me.city, me.jobTitle].join('\n');
```

Or maybe get fancy, and create some html on the fly:

```
document.getElementById("q1").innerHTML = [me.name, me.city, me.jobTitle].map(field => {
  return `<div class="some-class">${field}</div>`;
}).join('');
```

Comment: `join('')` <- you monster ;-). Also, newlines mean nothing (other than whitespace) to HTML

Comment: @poprox It's with a backslash. `\n` represents a new-line character in JavaScript. To see it in action, try typing this into the chrome console: `console.log('JavaScript\nrules!')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate in order of join strings in javascript. There are two ways you can do this;

a. addition operator (+)

```js
var a = "start the sentence,";
var b = " then join the sentence.";
var result = a + b;
```

b. concat() method

```js
var a = "start the sentence,";
var b = " then join the sentence.";
var result = a.concat(b);
```

both will result in the same answer.

Since you created an object, you can take the additional step of adding a method that returns your output.

```js
var me = {
  name: "Roxann",
  city: "Denver",
  jobTitle: "Paralegal",
   toString: function() {
     return this.name + "," + this.city + "," + this.jobTitle
   }   
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I remember now hearing the professor telling us about concatenate this or that. ok. thank you again!